# Is there a way of changing playback position using AudioKit / AKPlayer?

Tags: swift, audiokit

Been scratching my head with this one, to no avail.

Am just trying to find out how to instantly change the current playback position when using the AKAudioPlayer provided by AudioKit.

player.playhead is read-only, so cant be changed.

changing player.startTime whilst the player is already playing seems to change the playback position in terms of the reported .playhead position but the actual audio being played does not change position - am I missing something here?

Obviously I can stop audio and restart at new position but a several second expensive CPU gap is not desirable for a a simple mp3 / wav file player!

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not an answer, just a comment to also check out the other audio players in AudioKit.  I think you might find they serve your needs better. In fact, if you supply more information on your use case, I can probably suggest an alternative class to use as answer to this question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Aurelius - I love your AudioKit work! I am just trying to load a WAV, change it's playback position using a standard UI Slider - the docs say : .startTime "sets the start time, If it is playing, player will restart playing from the start time each time end time is set"

Comment: I am also seeking to then analyse the various FFT / Amplitude aspects of a WAV to pass details to other functions - which I have working using AKAudioPlayer - but I need to be able to change playback position!

Comment: I can't see any other alternative class other than the sample player perhaps... but this is for long tracks of say 30 minutes playback potentially...?

Comment: Perhaps AKClipPlayer is a better fit, have you looked at it?

Comment: OK hadn't seen that new class buried away - but YES! It did the trick, reading from disk and very snappy - perfect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Aurelius pointed me in the right direction of a new class introduced a couple weeks ago called [AKClipPlayer](http://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKClipPlayer.html)

Like the standard Apple AV class you can now set the .currentTime property (in seconds) (the AKAudioPlayer class did not allow this) - it seems to stop playback doing this though so don't forget to .play() your node right after - there is no glitch or pause, is seamless on an old iPhone6S

Answer (score 4):

We've added a new player called [AKPlayer](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/develop/AudioKit/Common/Nodes/Playback/Player/AKPlayer.swift) which will also allow scanning through the file. The player will stream from disk by default. This player is designed to fix some of the shortcomings in AKAudioPlayer.